# What happen when user location is near the Origin server more than CDN server?

Tags: cdn

When we use CDN, provider say that users will get static content on nearest server for faster loading speed...

But if users location is near the origin server more than CDN server then what happen?

Users will get cached content from CDN server or they will get content from Origin server? And what case will be faster?

(My case is that Origin server based in my country, I want users from global can access my site faster, but these big CDN providers does not have server in my country, I fear that users in my country will get slower loading speed compare to when I don't use CDN...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to using a CDN, then all your users will go through the CDN. If they don't have a server near you, then it is going to be slower for your local users. It's up to you to make a call on whether that tradeoff is worth it to gain the speed improvement for the international users. If you're mainly expecting local users for now, I would say you should avoid using a CDN for the sake of it.